# Measurable total order

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory, order-theory

Under what conditions on a metric space $X$, equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, does there exist a measurable total ordering of the elements of $X$?

By "measurable total ordering" we mean that any initial segment $I_y:=\{x: x<y\}$ is Borel-measurable.

Edit: We know that separability is sufficient for a measurable total order to exist.

Edit II: Vladimir Pestov (private communication) has shown that a measurable total order always exists; will post answer soon with link to full paper.

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for? Separability allows of course for a measurable embedding in $\mathbb{R}$, but there is no canonical non-separable totally ordered set.

Comment: Maybe an instructive counter-example (i.e., one where there is no measurable total order under the stated conditions)?

Comment: If $\dim X$ is finite then $X$ is the union of finitely many strongly zero-dimensional subspaces, all but one $F_\sigma$, the other $G_\delta$. Each is orderable so lay them end to end.

Comment: @KPHart see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the OP, Vladimir Pestov has answered the question affirmatively. See Appendix D here:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.09855.pdf